# Using Semantic UI:s star rating in sorting a table column?

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I'm wondering if there's a way to sort a table column with Semantic UI:s star rating-component? I'm using Javascript (jQuery tablesort plugin) for sorting all columns. Sorting works in all columns where theres string-type data. Here is the html-code for what's inside the star rating table data cell:

```
<td><div class="ui star rating" data-rating="3"></div></td>
```

Here's my table. 
http://kajlax.mbnet.fi/

Semantic UI:s rating-component.
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden span in the "td" with value corresponding with the number of stars

```
<td> <span style="visibility:hidden">3</span>
     <div class="ui star rating" data-rating="3"></div>
</td>
```